# How to use usb.modeswtich to turn my 4G dongle from mass storage mode to modem mode?

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, 4g

Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

My Huawei E3372 4G Dongle is not working correctly with Ubuntu. When I plug it in, I can see the `driver.exe` file is available (I installed wine so that I could run the .exe file) and it seems to install properly.

I still cant see my connection though and when using `lsusb` I notice that the device is recognised but is in 'Mass Storage Mode'.

I understand that usb.modeswitch can help me change this but I don't understand what I am supposed to do after reading conflicting information.

I can't find an up-to-date answer for my Ubuntu version

I am a complete linux and ubuntu noob, but I can follow instructions.. I just can't find a working solution to this problem online. Everything I try doesn't really seem to work.

Thanks

Update #1

Such a helpful community member @heynnema , thanks for this

It is a different modem but the exact same model, Huawei E3372h
lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 004: ID 03f0:3841 HP, Inc 
Bus 008 Device 005: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 017: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1     7-port Hub
Bus 008 Device 019: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.     E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 016: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub""
```

The rules. file contains the following only:

```
# Huawei E3372
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="14db",
```

RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"

Update #2

```
# Huawei E3372
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="14db", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

Comment: First, please confirm that *usb-modeswitch* is installed. From the terminal: `sudo dpkg -s usb-modeswitch | grep Status` If it is installed, remove the device and run: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Insert the device and then post the resulting terminal output and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pSGSByPTnV/

Comment: It appears that there was no output at all as you inserted the device. The device is seen in `lsusb` Please run and post: `dmesg | grep wxyz` Where 'wxyz' is the first four digits of the usb.id. For example, if `lsusb` shows 12d1:14fe, then we'd like to see: `dmesg | grep -i 12d1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at **/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules**, we see the following rules for Huawei comm devices...

```
# Generic entry for most Huawei devices, excluding Android phones
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{manufacturer}!="Android", ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="08", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"

# Huawei ME909u-521 (MBIM, dummy config)
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1573", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"

# Huawei ME906, ME909 (MBIM, dummy config)
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15c1", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

Your particular Huawei E3372 device is not being seen.

With the Huawei device inserted to your USB port, do `lsusb | grep -i 12d1` and you'll find output that includes `12d1:xxxx`, and it's the **xxxx** number that we care about.

**Note**: If **xxxx** is either 1573 or 15c1 then **stop** here. Your system should already recognize your Huawei device.

We need to create a new .rules file in **/etc/udev/rules.d/41-huawei_e3372.rules** that contains:

```
# Huawei E3372
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="xxxx", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

And changing the xxxx to the number we got from the prior `lsusb` command.

The file should look like this when you're done...

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42K Apr  2 15:46 41-huawei_e3372.rules
```

**Note**: `chmod` or `chown` if required.

You probably need to reboot, but if you just try to remove/insert the Huawei device, it may see it without a reboot. You're done.

**Note**: see `man usb_modeswitch_dispatcher` for more info.

Comment: @RickGao It depends on how much total power per USB hub the dongles take. Did you check your BIOS?

Comment: I will check bios and get back to you - unfortunately I can't reboot at the moment as some modems are in use right now as proxies. Thankyou

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127770/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-use-usb-modeswtich-to-turn-my-4g-dongle).

Comment: Thanks, just to add this works well for Raspbian too. Need a reboot, mode switched and ttyUSBn ports appeared.